# Showing a java widget in Kivy

Tags: kivy

is it possible to show a java widget (for example SpinnerDateModel) in an interface generated by Kivy?

The idea is to use some java widgets where Kivy does not provide equivalent widgets.

Comment: No, it's actually not possible, because of different instructions' calls. You'd need to either rewrite that widget so that it calls kivy instructions or make some bridge between these.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can use Pyjnius to acces some Java class - more on Kivy Planet: [Pyjnius: Accessing Java classes from Python](http://kivy.org/planet/2012/08/pyjnius-accessing-java-classes-from-python/) - but I don't know if you can do this with Java widget.